# How does nested component work in angular 5 or 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I was trying to learn how does two or more component communicate to each other in angular. hence after created an Angular project, I just created four new component named one, two, three and four.

After that, I was trying to add this code in app.component.html

```
<app-one> 
    <app-two>
        <app-three> </app-three>
    </app-two>
     <app-four> </app-four>
</app-one>
```

All the component has the same class as below :

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-one-child',
  templateUrl: './one-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one-child.component.css']
})
export class OneChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

by doing so I thought One will be the parent component of all of them and all will render. But unfortunately, I got only

```
one works!
```

while other components do not render at all. I am sure I am having some serious problem with angular and how it works. Can you please explain why it's not rendering the data from two, three and four? if I want to let them work what should I do?

Comment: what code do you have in your components classes?

Comment: @codeVerses i have updated the class information. please have a look. i just created all the component with ng g c one and so on. nothing fancy there. there are just new born component.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally each components template is responsible for its own html. IMO this would be the best way handle this.

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crs8oz)

*template for root component*

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  template: '<app-one></app-one>'
})
export class RootComponent{}
```

*template for component 1*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  template: '<app-two></app-two><app-four></app-four>'
})
export class Child1Component{}
```

*template for component 2*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-two',
  template: '<app-three></app-three>'
})
export class Child2Component{}
```

*template for component 3*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-three',
  template: '<h1>Hi there from 3</h1>'
})
export class Child3Component{}
```

*template for component 4*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-four',
  template: '<h1>Hi there from 4</h1>'
})
export class Child4Component{}
```

Comment: thank you very much. But can you tell me why the above is not working? is it because component one class has no idea about others?

Comment: @Kazi - See the linked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crs8oz) I just added.

Comment: @Kazi it does not work, because of transclusion. See my below answer about ng-content.

Answer (score 3):

If you need nested component, use `ng-content` in the parent ones, e.g.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'root',
  template: '<div>I'm root, <ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class RootComponent{}


@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<root>I'm children in the root</root>'
})
export class ChildComponent{}
```

and so on..

[See stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2svqs)

Then in your template, you can write:

```
<child></child>
```

It'll render `I'm root, I'm children in the root`

Or

```
<root>Hello world!</root>
```

It'll render `I'm root, Hello World!`

[Here is a great article about using ng-content (transclusion)](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b)